# Rails query, based on a scope from an unrelated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I want to find all of a user's `convos` where there is not a `connect`**

I have a `convos` table, with a `sender_id` and `recipient_id` which are both references to a user id

```
# app/models/user.rb

has_many :convos, ->(user) {
  unscope(:where).where("sender_id = :id OR recipient_id = :id", id: user.id)
}
```

Note the convo can belong to a user that is either sender_id OR recipient_id.

```
# app/models/convo.rb

class Convo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :msgs, dependent: :destroy

  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

  scope :involving, -> (user) do
    where("convos.sender_id =? OR convos.recipient_id =?",user.id,user.id)
  end

  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
    where("(convos.sender_id = ? AND convos.recipient_id =?) OR (convos.sender_id = ? AND convos.recipient_id =?)", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
end
```

`Connect` table has a `requestor_id` and `requestee_id` which are both references to a user id.
Connect model

```
class Connect < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :requestor, :foreign_key => :requestor_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :requestee, :foreign_key => :requestee_id, class_name: 'User'


  scope :between, -> (requestor_id,requestee_id) do
    where("(connects.requestor_id = ? AND connects.requestee_id =?) OR (connects.requestor_id = ? AND connects.requestee_id =?)", requestor_id,requestee_id, requestee_id, requestor_id)
  end
end
```

I want to find all of a user's `convos` where there is not a `connect`

I've tried something like:

```
user = User.first
user.convos.where.not(Connect.between(self.requestor_id, self.requestee_id).length > 0 )

# NoMethodError (undefined method `requestor_id' for main:Object)
```

---

```
user.convos.where.not(Connect.between(convo.requestor_id, convo.requestee_id).length > 0 )

# undefined local variable or method `convo' for main:Object
```

---

Then I tried without referencing a user at all, and just tried to get all convos without a connect.

```
Convo.where("Connect.between(? ,?) < ?)", :sender_id, :recipient_id, 1)

# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: near "between": syntax error: SELECT "convos".* FROM "convos" WHERE (Connect.between('sender_id' ,'recipient_id') < 1)))
```

---

```
Convo.where("Connect.between(? ,?) < ?)", self.sender_id, self.recipient_id, 1)

# NoMethodError (undefined method `sender_id' for main:Object)
```

---

What is the best way to get all the user's convos where a connect doesn't exist?

**UPDATE**

This works, and is what I'm looking for, but obviously this is trashy, and I'd like to understand how get this in 1 call.

```
@og_connections = []
current_user.convos.each do |convo|
   if Connect.between(convo.sender_id, convo.recipient_id).length === 0
     @og_connections.push(current_user.id === convo.sender_id ? convo.recipient_id : convo.sender_id)
   end
end
@connections = User.select(:id, :first_name, :slug).where(id: @og_connections, status: 'Active')
```

Comment: How does your convo model look like? Doesn't it have any relationship stated?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I updated to show the convo model.

Comment: Your example shows you're getting an user after all the procedures, but your question is _What is the best way to get all the __user's convos__ where a connect doesn't exist?_.

Comment: @ Sebastian Palma - Getting the user after all the proceedures? What does that mean? Are you looking at the bottom section under the word UPDATE? Both your answers are getting ALL the convos - I only want the convos associated with ONE user. Not every one in the database. Does that make more sense?

Comment: What I mean is this `User.select(:id, :first_name, :slug).where(id: @og_connections, status: 'Active')` returns users, not convos.

Comment: _I only want the convos associated with ONE user_, what convo user? `sender` or `recipient`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma -  A user can be associated to a convo through either sender or recipient. So both have to be checked. Same for connect - a user can be associated to a connect through either requestor or requestee. If you look at the update `current_user.convos.each do |convo|
   if Connect.between(convo.sender_id, convo.recipient_id).length === 0` -> How can I avoid this loop through convos, where it's comparing every convo to see if theres a connect?It doesn't matter how the user is associated to convo or connect-just that they are associated in the first place. Does this make more sense :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer with current setup

If you're looking for just `current_user`, you'll want to start with their `convos`, do a left join to `connects`, and select the rows where `connects` is `NULL`. With your table setup, we'll have to do this joins manually on the possible user_id combinations:

```
current_user.convos.joins("
  LEFT JOIN connects ON
    (connects.requestor_id = convos.sender_id AND connects.requestee_id = convos.recipient_id)
    OR
    (connects.requestor_id = convos.recipient_id AND connects.requestee_id = convos.sender_id)
  ").where(connects: {id: nil})
```

The left joins gives you any connects that are between the same two users as the convo, which is necessarily involving `current_user` since we started with `current_user.convos`. From there we filter down to only rows where the `connects` fields are `NULL`, getting us rows with a convo that does *not* have a matching connect.

---

### Suggestion

That much raw SQL is a bit of code smell in a Rails app, and it's because of what we're trying to do here with the models set up as they are. I'd suggest refactoring the data models to make the queries easier. Two ideas come to mind:

1. Always create a symmetrical record for a connect and a convo, so you can look up by a single column instead of using all the `OR`s. That is, whenever you create a `connect` between user 1 and user 2, also create one between user 2 and user 1. More bookkeeping, since you'd have to destroy and edit them together as well. But it lets you . define simple associations without all the hoops.
2. Use a separate table to refer to unique user-pairs (order doesn't matter). To do this, create a `UserPair` model with `user_1_id` and `user_2_id`, where `user_1_id` is always set to the lower of the two user ids. That way, a convo can be more easily identified by a `user_pair_id`, a `UserPair` can `has_many :convos` and `has_many: connects`, and you can to a straight rails join between `convos -> user_pairs -> connects`.

The models in 2 would look something like

```
class UserPair < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_1, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :user_2, class_name: "User"

  before_save :sort_users

  scope :between, -> (user_1_id,user_2_id) do
    # records are always saved in sorted id order, so sort before querying
    user_1_id, user_2_id = [user_1_id, user_2_id].sort
    where(user_1_id: user_1_id, user_2_id: user_2_id)
  end

  # always put lowest id first for easy lookup
  def sort_users
    if user_1.present? && user_2.present? && user_1.id > user_2.id
      self.user_1, self.user_2 = user_2, user_1
    end
  end
end

class Convo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :user_pair

  before_validation :set_user_pair

  scope :involving, -> (user) do
    where("convos.sender_id =? OR convos.recipient_id =?",user.id,user.id)
  end

  # since UserPair records are always user_id sorted, we can just use
  # that model's scope here without need to repeat it, using `merge`
  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
    joins(:user_pair).merge(UserPair.between(sender_id, recipient_id))
  end

  def set_user_pair
    self.user_pair = UserPair.find_or_initialize_by(user_1: sender, user_2: recipient)
  end
end
```

Comment: The first statement works perfect. Thank you sooo much

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to get the users rows where their match between `id` and `convos.sender_id` and `convos.recipient_id` is not `NULL`, but their match between `connections.requester_id` and `connections.requestee_id` is `NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT JOIN connects
ON users.id IN (connects.requester_id, connects.requestee_id)
LEFT JOIN convos
ON users.id IN (convos.sender_id, convos.recipient_id)
WHERE connects.requester_id IS NULL AND
      connects.requestee_id IS NULL AND
      convos.sender_id      IS NOT NULL AND
      convos.recipient_id   IS NOT NULL
```

AR implementation:

```
User.joins('LEFT JOIN connects ON users.id IN (connects.requester_id, connects.requestee_id)
            LEFT JOIN convos   ON users.id IN (convos.sender_id, convos.recipient_id)')
    .where(connects: { requester_id: nil, requestee_id: nil })
    .where.not(convos: { sender_id: nil, recipient_id: nil })
```

---

Considering a DB structure like this:

```
db=# \d+ users
                                                              Table "public.users"
   Column   |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |              Default              | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 name       | character varying              |           |          |                                   | extended |              |
 created_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              |
 updated_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |                                   | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

db=# \d+ convos
                                                              Table "public.convos"
    Column    |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |              Default               | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id           | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('convos_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
 sender_id    | integer                        |           |          |                                    | plain   |              |
 recipient_id | integer                        |           |          |                                    | plain   |              |
 created_at   | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |                                    | plain   |              |
 updated_at   | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |                                    | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "convos_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

db=# \d+ connects
                                                              Table "public.connects"
    Column    |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |               Default                | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id           | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('connects_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
 requestor_id | integer                        |           |          |                                      | plain   |              |
 requestee_id | integer                        |           |          |                                      | plain   |              |
 created_at   | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |                                      | plain   |              |
 updated_at   | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null |                                      | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "connects_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

With the following records:

```
db=# select * from users;
 id | name |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | seb  | 2019-11-27 09:59:53.762911 | 2019-11-27 09:59:53.762911
  2 | sab  | 2019-11-27 09:59:55.455096 | 2019-11-27 09:59:55.455096
  3 | foo  | 2019-11-27 10:07:19.760675 | 2019-11-27 10:07:19.760675
  4 | bar  | 2019-11-27 10:07:36.18696  | 2019-11-27 10:07:36.18696
  5 | meh  | 2019-11-27 10:07:38.465841 | 2019-11-27 10:07:38.465841
(5 rows)

db=# select * from convos;
 id | sender_id | recipient_id |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 |         1 |            2 | 2019-11-27 10:09:36.742426 | 2019-11-27 10:09:36.742426
  2 |         1 |            3 | 2019-11-27 10:09:40.555118 | 2019-11-27 10:09:40.555118
(2 rows)

db=# select * from connects;
 id | requestor_id | requestee_id |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+--------------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 |            1 |            2 | 2019-11-27 10:07:07.76146  | 2019-11-27 10:07:07.76146
  2 |            2 |            1 | 2019-11-27 10:07:11.380084 | 2019-11-27 10:07:11.380084
  3 |            1 |            4 | 2019-11-27 10:07:47.892944 | 2019-11-27 10:07:47.892944
  4 |            5 |            1 | 2019-11-27 10:07:51.406224 | 2019-11-27 10:07:51.406224
(4 rows)
```

The following query will return only the second convo, because user with id 3 doesn't have any connect.

```
SELECT convos.*
FROM convos
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.id IN (convos.sender_id, convos.recipient_id)
LEFT JOIN connects
ON users.id IN (connects.requestor_id, connects.requestee_id)
WHERE connects.requestor_id IS NULL AND connects.requestee_id IS NULL

 id | sender_id | recipient_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         | id | name |         created_at         |         updated_at         | id | requestor_id | requestee_id | created_at | updated_at
----+-----------+--------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----+--------------+--------------+------------+------------
  2 |         1 |            3 | 2019-11-27 10:09:40.555118 | 2019-11-27 10:09:40.555118 |  3 | foo  | 2019-11-27 10:07:19.760675 | 2019-11-27 10:07:19.760675 |    |              |              |            |
(1 row)
```

The Rails query for that can be this:

```
Convo
  .joins('LEFT JOIN users ON users.id IN (convos.sender_id, convos.recipient_id)
          LEFT JOIN connects ON users.id IN (connects.requestor_id, connects.requestee_id)')
  .where(connects: { requestor_id: nil, requestee_id: nil })
```

Comment: Is this checking both scenarios? A user can be either sender_id or recipient_id (same for connects). As well - I'm confused how to clarify which user I'm wanting the results for. Thanks!

Comment: can you look at my update? Your answer doesn't get what I'm looking for, but it's a good start. Thanks - appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, from the list of users a user has a conversation with, you want the list of users that they do not have a connection with.

In a simple way this could be something like:

```
users_conversed_with = user.convos.map{|c| [c.sender_id, c.recipient_id]}.flatten.uniq 
users_connected_with = user.connections.map{|c| c.requestor_id, c.requestee_id}.flatten.uniq
```

Both sets also contain the `user.id`, but we can ignore that, because we are interested in the difference: that would be the set of people we conversed with, without connection (and because `user.id` will be in both, unless one of them is empty, we do not have to separately remove `user.id` from those sets).

```
users_not_connected_with = users_conversed_with - users_connected_with
```

This is not an optimal approach, because we do two queries, retrieve all the user-ids from the database, to then discard probably most of the retrieved data. We could improve this by creating a custom query, and let the database do the work for us, like so

```
 sql = <<-SQL
   (select distinct user_id from 

     (select sender_id as user_id from convos where sender_id=#{user.id} or recipient_id=#{user.id}
      union
      select recipient_id as user_id from convos where sender_id=#{user.id} or recipient_id=#{user.id}
     )
   )
   except
   (
   (select distinct user_id from          
     (select requestor_id as user_id from connections where requestor_id=#{user.id} or requestee_id=#{user.id}
      union
      select requestee_id as user_id from convos where requestor_id=#{user.id} or requestee_id=#{user.id}
     )
   ) 
 SQL  

 result = Convo.connection.execute(sql)
 users_ids_in_convo_without_connection = result.to_a.map(&:values).flatten
```

But if performance is not an issue, your code has the advantage of being very readable and clearer in it's intention.

Answer (score 0):

I'll first write the SQL query to do so. In your case you perhaps want

```
SELECT convos.*
FROM convos
WHERE (sender_id = :user_id
        AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM connects
         WHERE (requestor_id = sender_id AND requestee_id = recipient_id) OR (requestor_id = recipient_id AND requestee_id = sender_id)
        ))
  OR        
    (recipient_id = :user_id
       AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM connects
        WHERE (requestor_id = recipient_id AND requestee_id = sender_id) OR (requestor_id = sender_id AND requestee_id = recipient_id)
    ))
```

This can be then converted into AR query.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Convo < ApplicationRecord
  def self.no_connects(user_id = nil)
    q = joins('
      LEFT JOIN connects ON
        sender_id IN (connects.requestor_id, connects.requestee_id)
          OR
        recipient_id IN (connects.requestor_id, connects.requestee_id)
    ')
    q = q.where('connects.requestor_id IS NULL AND connects.requestee_id IS NULL')
    q = q.where("convos.sender_id = :user_id OR convos.recipient_id = :user_id", user_id: user_id) if user_id
    q
  end
end
```

To get all the convos without connects

`Convo.no_connects`

For single user

`Convo.no_connects(current_user.id)`